# How to Convert following String to Json using Java?

Tags: java

I need to convert the following string into json format.

Below is the input as well as the expected output for reference.

Input:

```
Employee Driver Report - EDR
--------------------------------
Employee Nbr: 123480 Employee Type: DI Cat: UPL
Driver License: PP3P30 Plate: ROWP
Part Number: 1006096
```

Output:

```
{
"Employee Nbr": "123480",
"Employee Type": "DI",
"Cat": "UPL",
"Driver License": "PP3P30",
"Plate": "ROWP",
"Part Number": "1006096",
}
```

Sample Code:

```
Map<String, String> keyValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] lines = rawText.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
for(String line: lines) {
.......
   keyValueMap.put(keyAndValues[i], keyAndValues[i + 1]);
}
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(keyValueMap);
```

Could you please help me on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a bit missing from your spec; for instance, how do we decide that it is `"Employee Nbr": "123480", "Employee Type": "DI",` and not `"Employee Nbr": "123480 Employee", "Type": "DI",`? Assuming correctly formatted files and only a single word for each value, I'd split by spaces, collect words until hitting one ending in `:`, use the collection as the key, then take the next word as the value, and repeat until everything is consumed.

Comment: Assuming it is corrected formatted. Sorry that forget to miss one thing..Also it has to consider space as well..for example if the following comes in single line  Emp Number: First Class: should return json as { Emp Number: , First Class} . right now it is wrongly coming as "Emp Number": "First" in the json output

Comment: Thanks for the additional spec information; that makes things a bit harder to handle with a regular expression, although it probably can be done (and if this is a homework problem, you might lose points for being too clever or having grabbed it off the internet!); If we go back to splitting by spaces, if when collecting the keys, if you get one but there are no more words left on the line, you append the current key onto the end of the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

For each `line` you get, you have to parse it using `:` and  (space) as delimiters.

I'll let you search the correct regex to use and ask for help if needed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expression like so: `([\w\s]+\s*):\s*([\w]+)` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/rR2hZ1/4)) to process the data. This expression assumes that there is no white space within your value parameters.

Thus given the code below:

```
    String source = "Employee Driver Report - EDR\n" +
                    "--------------------------------\n" +
                    "Employee Nbr: 123480 Employee Type: DI Cat: UPL\n" +
                    "Driver License: PP3P30 Plate: ROWP\n" +
                    "Part Number: 1006096";

    String[] lines = source.split("\n");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]+\\s*):\\s*([\\w]+)");
    System.out.println("{");
    for(int i = 2; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(lines[i]);
        while(m.find())
        {                
            System.out.println("\"" + m.group(2).trim() + "\":" + "\"" + m.group(1).trim() + "\"");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("}");
```

You would get something like so:

```
{
"Employee Nbr":"123480"
"Employee Type":"DI"
"Cat":"UPL"
"Driver License":"PP3P30"
"Plate":"ROWP"
"Part Number":"1006096"
}
```

EDIT: As per your comment:

```
    String source = "Employee Driver Report - EDR\n" +
                    "--------------------------------\n" +
                    "Employee Nbr: 123480 With white space Employee Type: DI Cat: UPL\n" +
                    "Driver License: PP3P30 Plate: ROWP\n" +
                    "Part Number: 1006096";

    String[] lines = source.split("\n");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Employee Nbr|Employee Type|Cat|Driver License|Plate|Part Number)\\s*:\\s*(.+?)(?:(?=Employee Nbr|Employee Type|Cat|Driver License|Plate|Part Number)|$)");
    System.out.println("{");
    for(int i = 2; i < lines.length; i++)
    {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(lines[i]);
        while(m.find())
        {                
            System.out.println("\"" + m.group(1).trim() + "\":" + "\"" + m.group(2).trim() + "\"");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("}");
```

Yields:

```
{
"Employee Nbr":"123480 With white space"
"Employee Type":"DI"
"Cat":"UPL"
"Driver License":"PP3P30"
"Plate":"ROWP"
"Part Number":"1006096"
}
```

A description of the updated expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/rR2hZ1/5).

Comment: Thanks for the expression..Sorry that forget to miss one thing..it has to consider space as well..for example if the following comes in single line  Emp Number: First Class: should return json as { Emp Number: , First Class} . right now it is wrongly coming as "Emp Number": "First" in the json output

Comment: @KathiresanJeyapandian: Will the key values such as `Employee Nbr`, `Employee Type` always be there? You could use those as markers.

Comment: so npinti how to get the expected output by considering the above